# Keeping state in a Picasso Transformation

Tags: picasso

I need to apply different border thicknesses in a transformation. That is, the left side could be 10dp and the top 8dp, etc. for each cell in a `GridView`.

I have a `Transformation` with local variables for the thicknesses which I apply in `transform` using Canvas drawing primitives. This all works and the drawing is happening.

My question: because each transformation has different parameters it means I have to create a new transformation for each cell (in my adapter), set its properties and pass it to the Picasso builder.

I read elsewhere that transformations should not be created multiple times and they can be re-used. But thats not really possible in my scenario since each transformation has different state.

Am I doing this right and/or whats the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are truly dynamic you will have to create a new instance for every call. It's not the end of the world to do this, it's only a single, small allocation. Most transformers are completely stateless and it makes sense to re-use the same instance.

You could also pool these objects, but it's needlessly complicated. You have to deal with request joining, canceling, and the asynchronous nature of how they're used. Unless it becomes a problem, just pay the cost of the allocation.

If the range of values is limited or you are using the same values over and over you could cache those instances in a map.